# How to create line graph dynamically like this image

Tags: android, paint, android-graphview

[Line Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cysmp.png)

I have 5 dynamic data which is giving +1 or -1 as result, if the result is +1 then graph direction is towards up and if the result is -1 then graph direction is towards downward.

Comment: Check this link : https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image in your question is not available to view but i can put a sample for how to draw a line chart in your android app easily.

First -as mentioned in comment- you can use `MPAndroidChart`. You can add it to your project like following:

```
 implementation "com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3"
```

Here's a sample default line chart implementation which i use in my personal projects.

```
open class DefaultLineChart @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyle: Int = 0)
    : LineChart(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    init {
        setupChart()
    }

    private fun setupChart() {

        // Init Description
        val description = Description().apply {
            isEnabled = false
        }
        setDescription(description)

        // Init GridBackground
        setGridBackgroundColor(android.R.color.white)
        setDrawGridBackground(true)

        // Init Borders
        setDrawBorders(true)
        setBorderColor(android.R.color.black)
        setBorderWidth(1f)

        // Init Other Properties
        setPinchZoom(false)
        isDoubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
        isDragEnabled = true
        setNoDataText(context.getString(R.string.info_text_no_content))
        setScaleEnabled(true)

        // Init Legend
        val legend = legend.apply {
            isEnabled = false
        }

        // Init xAxis
        val xAxis = xAxis.apply {
            isEnabled = true
            setCenterAxisLabels(false)
            gridColor = android.R.color.white
            setAvoidFirstLastClipping(false)
            setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true)
            position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
        }


        // Init leftAxis
        val leftAxis = axisLeft.apply {
            axisMinimum = 0f
            setDrawAxisLine(false)
            setDrawZeroLine(true)
            setDrawGridLines(true)
            gridColor = android.R.color.black
            axisLineColor = android.R.color.black
        }

        val rightAxis = axisRight.apply {
            isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    fun setChartTitle(title: String) {
        val description = Description().apply {
            text = title
            isEnabled = true
        }
        setDescription(description)
    }
}
```

You can add it to your xml layout like below:

```
<path_to_your_class.DefaultLineChart
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="400dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
```

Finally you can draw your chart like following code:

```
fun bindDefaultLineChart(chartView: LineChart,
                                 marketValues: List<MarketVal>?,
                                 label: String?) {
            if (marketValues == null) {
                return
            }

            val yValues = ArrayList<Entry>()
            var maxCount: Long = 0
            for (marketValue in marketValues) {
                val entry = Entry(marketValue.dateTime.toFloat(),
                        marketValue.transactionNumber.toFloat())
                yValues.add(entry)
                if (marketValue.transactionNumber > maxCount) {
                    maxCount = marketValue.transactionNumber.toLong()
                }
            }

            val xAxis = chartView.xAxis
            val xAxisFormatter = ChartValueDateFormatter(Constants.DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT)
            xAxis.valueFormatter = xAxisFormatter

            chartView.axisLeft.apply {
                axisMaximum = (maxCount + MAX_CHAR_Y_AXIS_ADDITION).toFloat()
                valueFormatter = NonFloatValueFormatter()
            }

            val dataSet = LineDataSet(yValues, label).apply {
                axisDependency = YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT
                color = ContextCompat.getColor(chartView.context, R.color.colorAccent)
                formLineWidth = 2f
                setDrawIcons(true)
                setDrawValues(false)
            }

            val lineData = LineData(dataSet)
            chartView.data = lineData
        }
}
```

You can find example implementation from [here](https://github.com/savepopulation/blockchain-tracker).